# python base64 encode to string

Tags: python, string, encoding, base64

I want to encode some data as Base64, and then have the encoded data concatenated in a string.

when I do:

```
four=base64.urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(MAIL, "utf-8"))
print (four)
```

result will be:

```
b'YWxleEBhbGV4LmFsZXg='
```

I want to remove the b'' from four. So that only YWxleEBhbGV4LmFsZXg= is shown.
How do I go about getting just the string YWxleEBhbGV4LmFsZXg= withouth the byte type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a `bytes` object; decode it to Unicode:

```
print(four.decode('ascii'))
```

Base64 only uses ASCII characters, so that's a good codec do use here. If you don't explicitly decode, `print()` can only use the `repr()` representation, which produces *Python literal syntax*, the syntax you'd use to create the same value as a literal.

Comment: worked like a charm. Thank you for the explanation.

I used hexdigest() for a sha1 hash that also had extra text, but this wouldn't work for the base64 encoded element. the .decode('ascii') worked though.